# I tried to disentangle an exponential of a sum of operators of the type below, but it lead to a different result from that mentioned in the article

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, group-theory, lie-algebra

could you explain  how we get to equations 10 please, or indicate the formula used. help me  mathematiciens ! :)

[image]

Comment: I know that we have to use the commutators in equation 9, but what is the formula we can use in this case

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes i understand the  answer. Thank you very much @CosmasZachos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [braiding identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Special_cases) which works for ladder operators:
$$
[X,Y]=sY ~~~~\implies\\
 \bbox[yellow,5px]{ e^{sY + X}=e^{(e^s-1)Y} e^X} ~.
$$
It follows from the adjoint dilation considerations in WP.

Crudely, the unified exponential operator solutions of your equations (8) yield an exponential of the sum of ${\cal R+L}$ and  ${\cal M}$,  which ladder with each other as above, and  ${\cal R-L}$, which commutes with those two, so *it factors out in an exponentials' product reduction*! For instance, the first equation in (8) is solved by
$$
\rho_{ee} (t)= e^{tk(2{\cal M} -({\cal R+L}))} e^{ -it\Omega ({\cal R-L})}\rho_{ee} (0).
$$

So, first you apply the above identity with the suitable identification of operators, $Y=2kt{\cal M} $, $~X=-tk({\cal R+L}) $, having already factored out the exponential of ${\cal R-L}$; then the triple product of exponentials of ${\cal M}$,  ${\cal R+L}$, and  ${\cal R-L}$ can rearrange to those of the first of (10), since $[{\cal R, L}]=0$, so the rightmost two exponentials can be rearranged to  a product of two exponentials of ${\cal R}$ and ${\cal L}$, as given!

Comment: your  answer is very  clear. many thanks :)@Cosmas Zachos

Comment: it is done @Cosmas Zachos :)